# How do you create a link in a Google Maps InfoWindow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

#### The Preamble

I want to create a list of google map markers which populate InfoWindows about those specific locations and inside the InfoWindow a link to the Wikipedia article about that location.  I am making an **Ajax** call within this `google.maps.event.addListener(place.marker, 'click', function() {}` click function, and this function is within a `self.allPlaces().forEach(function(place) {}` function that just iterates through all my locations.

#### The Problem

The link is populated within the InfoWindows, **but** it only opens if you right click and open in a new tab, whereas I would like it to just open with a left click.

```
function ajax() {
            return $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: wikiURL,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                prop: 'pageimages'
            });
        }

        ajax().done(function(response) {
            clearTimeout(self.apiTimeout);
            var articleList = response[1];
            console.log(response);
            if (articleList.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < articleList.length; i++) {
                    var url = response[3]; // response[3] gives back the wiki URL
                    content = '<div class="infoWindow"><strong>' + place.title + '</strong><br>' +
                                '<p>' + place.formatted_address + '</p>' +
                                '<p>' + response[2] + '</p>' + // response[2] for more modern response
                                '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' +
                                "View full Wikipedia article" + '</a>' +
                    '</div>';
                    infoWindow.setContent(content);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your implementation might do something with the error. Check if the created `content` variable look like the code sample `contentString` variable

Try and follow the sample code in the [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple).

Code Sample:

```
var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
'<div id="siteNotice">'+
'</div>'+
'<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
'<div id="bodyContent">'+
'<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
'(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
'Heritage Site.</p>'+
'<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
'(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>';
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentString
});
```